# Is there any field of characteristic 4 or any other composite number?

Tags: linear-algebra, finite-fields

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Characteristic of a field is $0$ or prime](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/86263/characteristic-of-a-field-is-0-or-prime)

Is there any field of characteristic 4? Or any other composite number?

Comment: No, the characteristic must be a prime.  See [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/77625/15941) for a discussion of this point.

Comment: Also related: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/53877/is-there-anything-like-gf6/53878#53878, http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/48595/characteristic-of-residue-field-and-characteristic-of-the-ring/48601#48601

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, a field $F$ can only have prime characteristic:

Let $a \neq 0 \in F$. If $(mn)a = 0$ then also $m(na)=0$. If $(na) \neq 0$ then $F$ has characteristic $\leq m$. If not, then $F$ has characteristic $\leq n$. Either way, the characteristic is $< mn$. This implies that a field must have characteristic prime or zero.

EDIT: Changed to additive notation.

Comment: Your post should be edited to include the case that the characteristic is zero.

Comment: @AndréNicolas, Dilip: Thanks for the correction. I even confused myself. The answer should make more sense now.

Answer (score 4):

This is a small variation on Fredrik Meyer's answer.

$0$ and $1 \neq 0$ are the additive and multiplicative identities in a field
$\mathbb F$.

- If $1$, $1+1$, $1+1+1, \cdots$ are all distinct elements of $\mathbb F$,
  then the *characteristic* of $\mathbb F$ is said to be $0$. Note that
  $\mathbb F$ contains (at least) a countably infinite number of elements.
- If $1$, $1+1$, $1+1+1, \cdots$ are *not* all distinct, then if we
  have for some $i$ and $j$,  $i < j$, that
  $$
  \underbrace{1+ \cdots + 1}_{i~\text{ones}} 
  = \underbrace{1+ \cdots + 1}_{j~\text{ones}}
  = \underbrace{1+ \cdots + 1}_{i~\text{ones}} 
  + \underbrace{1+ \cdots + 1}_{j-i~\text{ones}},
  $$
  we can conclude that $\underbrace{1+ \cdots + 1}_{j-i~\text{ones}} = 0$.
  The *smallest integer* $N > 1$ such that $\underbrace{1+ \cdots + 1}_{N~\text{ones}} = 0$ is called the characteristic of the field.
  (The possibility that $N$ could be $1$ is ruled out by the fact $1 \neq 0$
  in a field).  $N$ must be a prime number because if $N$ were composite,
  say $N = mn$ with $m,n > 1$, then from
  $$
  0 = \underbrace{1+ \cdots + 1}_{mn~\text{ones}} 
  = \left(\underbrace{1+ \cdots + 1}_{m~\text{ones}}\right)
  \times \left(\underbrace{1+ \cdots + 1}_{n~\text{ones}}\right),
  $$
  we get that at least one of $\underbrace{1+ \cdots + 1}_{m~\text{ones}}$
  and  $\underbrace{1+ \cdots + 1}_{n~\text{ones}}$ is $0$, that is,
  fewer than $N$ $1$'s sum to $0$ in contradiction of the definition of $N$.

Thus the characteristic of field is either $0$ or a prime number.