# What is the smallest element of $\{n\in \mathbb N^*\mid \underbrace{1+...+1}_{n\ times}=0\}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory

Let $R$ be a field and consider $$A=\{n\in \mathbb N^*\mid \underbrace{1+...+1}_{n\ times}=0\}.$$
Assuming that it's not empty, prove that its smallest element is prime.

I have no idea how to do it. It looks here that we are in $\mathbb Z/n\mathbb Z$ and since $R$ is a field and that $A$ might be a subfield, then $n$ will be prime, but this don't answer the question since they ask for the smallest element.

If my question is unclear, let me know.

Comment: $A$ cannot be a subfield because it is a set of integers, not a subset of the field at all. It is _almost_ an ideal of $\mathbb Z$, except that it lacks the non-positive elements.

Comment: By the way, what is $\mathbb N^*$?

Comment: @HenningMakholm: What could it be except $\mathbb N\backslash \{0\}$ ?

Comment: See [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/92743/is-there-any-field-of-characteristic-4-or-any-other-composite-number?noredirect=1&lq=1).

Answer (score 2):

Assume its smallest element $n$ is not prime and write $n=ab$ where $a\geq 2$, $b\geq 2$. Then:
$$\underbrace{(\underbrace{1+...+1}_{a\ times})+(\underbrace{1+...+1}_{a\ times})+\cdots+(\underbrace{1+...+1}_{a\ times})}_{b\ times}=0$$
Rewrite this as
$$b\cdot(\underbrace{1+...+1}_{a\ times})=0.$$
Can you spot a contradiction?

Comment: Either $b=0$ or $a=0$ ? which contradict $a,b\geq 2$ ? But don't we directly have that $ab=n=0$ which is a contradiction ?

Comment: but $b$ is not an element of $R$

Comment: $b$ is shorthand for $b\cdot 1$ which is well defined.

Comment: Actually, writing it as $$(\underbrace{1+\cdots+1}_{b\text{ times}})\cdot(\underbrace{1+\cdots+1}_{a\text{ times}})=0$$ would be clearer. - @user352653: The originally assumed $n=ab$ is an equation _in the integers_, not in $R$, so $n\ne 0$ by assumption.